# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 708434944 into shape (224,224,3)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, jupyter

I'm trying to reshape my array `x_train` to (-1, 224, 224, 3) for `VGG16 model`.

When the code is run, an error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 708434944 into shape (224,224,3)

appears, noting that the amount of data is `(14119)`.

But this error does not appear when I run `x_valid` and the amount of data `(660)`.

This is the reference:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/shiv28/ocr-handwritten/notebook

I am trying to apply to VGG16.

My dataset is like this, is it affected in reshape?

[image]

Comment: Your data could be reshaped into a (14119, 224, 224) array - but there's no factor of three in the size, so nothing like (..., 3) is possible.  Perhaps these images are monochrome, but you're trying to apply some process that's designed for RGB color images?

Comment: @jasonharper Do you mean that because the dataset is black and white, it does not work? But I did a treatment for it and saved it in jpg format before

Answer (score 2):

> cannot reshape array of size 708434944 into shape (224,224,3)

because the product of `244*244*3` is not equal to `708434944`.

Example:

If you have a 1D array of shape `(100,)` you can reshape it to `(10,10)` or `(2,50)` or `(50,2)` or `(2,10,5)` etc because its product is equal to `100`.

Comment: Wow, excellent explanation of the error-cause and what formula needs to be satisfied to prevent it.